# Can someone please explain the difference between an electric charge and electric current?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, electric-current, charge, definition

Well I understand the definition my question was that we measure charge by calculating 6.24 *10 powers 28 in one second then what is electricity if it is the rate of flow of charge is,t it's the same thing then again current formula is different can someone please explain

Comment: It's not clear what you don't understand. Do you understand the difference between water and the current in a river? (i.e. water is still water if it's standing still, it only becomes a current when it is moving)

Comment: Just some punctuation would render the question intelligible. As such it's near-gibberish.

Comment: Current = Charge/time (the simplest definition). Are you not familiar with this?

Comment: Well thank you Mr photon for the answer I just don,t get that the formula that we use to measure columbs is Q = I*t charge is still right like water so how we calculate it by multiplying current with time charge is not flowing right and in its formula it is saying if 6.24 * 10 powers 28 is flowing in a circuit in one second thats one columb

Answer (score 1):

An electric current is a movement of electric charges through an area in a time interval.
The more charges that pass through the area in a fixed time  then the larger the current.
If the charges flow in one direction the current is called a direct current and if the charges spend half their time flowing in  the other direction too then this is called alternating current.

Answer (score 0):

$$\text{Current} = \frac{\text{Charge}}{\text{time}}$$

so if the time equals 1 second then the numerical value of the charge and current will be the same. When a charge of 1 Coulomb flows in one second it results in a current of 1 Ampere.

(The units for the charge are not stated in your question.)

Comment: Hello! I have taken the liberty to edit your answer in a way that makes it better in my opinion - if you don't like it, feel free to rollback!

Comment: Thanks, it is better now.